# Unable to open or view data with python

Tags: pandas, dask, python-xarray

I have a netcdf3 dataset that I need to get into a data frame (preferable pandas) for further manipulation but am unable to do so. Since the data is multi hierarchical, I am first reading it in xarray then converting it to pandas using the to_dataframe command. This has worked well on other data, but it just kills the kernel in this case. I have tried converting it to a netcdf4 file using ncks but still cannot open it. I have also tried calling a single row or column of the xarray data structure just to view it, and this similarly kills the kernel. I produced this data so it is probably not corrupted. Does anyone have any experience with this? The file size is about 890 MB if that's relevant.

I am running python 2.7 on a Mac.

Comment: I have also tried converting from a dask dataframe to pandas or viewing the dask dataframe but both kill the kernel. .compute also kills it.

Comment: Can you view it in xarray without converting it to a dataframe?

Comment: no, not able to view it at all except using ncdump + etc in terminal. But, lots of further manipulation is needed on this data, as it is model output.

Comment: It is unlikely you are actually calling anything in dask here

Comment: How are you trying to open it in xarray? What errors are you receiving?  We need much more information to be able to help.